# From c++ map container to matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm converting a C++ code to Matlab. However, I'm facing a difficulty in converting the map to matlab syntax.

The c++ instructions using map are the following:

```
using  kp_idx_t = size_t;
using img_idx_t = size_t;

std::map<kp_idx_t, std::map<img_idx_t, kp_idx_t>> kp_matches; 

kp_idx_t& kp_match_idx(size_t kp_idx, size_t img_idx) { return kp_matches[kp_idx][img_idx]; };
bool kp_match_exist(size_t kp_idx, size_t img_idx) { return kp_matches[kp_idx].count(img_idx) > 0; };
```

How to convert them to matlab?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing directly equivalent to `std::map` in Matlab.  So my answer to "How to convert them to Matlab?" is ... it depends on what you are trying to do.

I don't exactly follow your code or have any idea of what you use the maps for but if you are doing things like this is c++:

```
  std::map<char,int> first;
  first['a']=10;
  first['b']=30;
  first['c']=50;
```

You could maybe use a structure in Matlab:

```
first.a = 10;
first.b = 20;
first.c = 30;
```

Then you can use Matlab's dynamic field names sort of like keys.

```
myKey = 'a';
first.(myKey)
```

which would return `10`

Comment: Matlab provides: containers.Map